# How to remove all SDK and Multi-targeting .NET's?

Tags: frameworks

The command `wmic product where "Name like 'Microsoft .Net%'" get Name, Version` shows the following list of installed (?) .NET's:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi-Targeting Pack                                                                       4.5.50932
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi-Targeting Pack                                                                         4.5.50710
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 RC Multi-Targeting Pack for Windows Store Apps                                             4.5.21005
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 SDK                                                                                          4.5.50710
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 RC Multi-Targeting Pack for Windows Store Apps (ENU)                                       4.5.21005
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 (RUS)                                                                                      4.6.01055
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Multi-Targeting Pack                                                                           4.0.30319
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
```

So I'm wondering how to remove them all?

I tried [dotnetfx_cleanup_tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) but nothing changed...

Also I cheked *KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP* - there is no 4.* there... Nevertheless **wmic** gets the list from somewhere...

Thank you!

Comment: How about [bulk crap uninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/)?

Answer (score 6):

I had big success with [Total Uninstaller](https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller)

Got rid of all my Visual Studio bloat and other things too

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: its an uninstaller that runs without installing. Let it search for "Multi-Targeting Pack" and it will unistall trhem without fuss

Comment: Incredibly but this works! Even in the case when the Windows Installer can't remove  its software due to (prerequisites checks?) errors.